# Could not find module ‘Criterion.Main’

Tags: haskell, haskell-criterion

I have copied the following code from criterion tutorial:

```
import Criterion.Main

-- The function we're benchmarking.
fib m | m < 0     = error "negative!"
      | otherwise = go m
  where
    go 0 = 0
    go 1 = 1
    go n = go (n-1) + go (n-2)

-- Our benchmark harness.
main = defaultMain [
  bgroup "fib" [ bench "1"  $ whnf fib 1
               , bench "5"  $ whnf fib 5
               , bench "9"  $ whnf fib 9
               , bench "11" $ whnf fib 11
                ]
     ]
```

I am getting the following error:

fiber.hs:1:1: error:
Could not find module ‘Criterion.Main’
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
|
1 | import Criterion.Main
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

The GHC version I am using is 8.4.2 and cabal version is 2.2.0.0.

I tried to install the criterion package by:

```
cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
To revert to previous state run: cabal update --index-state='2018-06- 
01T04:23:08Z'

cabal install -j --disable-tests criterion
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nopie' [-Wunused- 
command-line-argument]
.
.
.
.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
abstract-deque-0.3-IvBVpgU2tvq3eILHsBTjFR failed during the building 
phase.
The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
aeson-1.3.1.1-J9Jy9Bz77dxJho59OWZvUt depends on aeson-1.3.1.1 which 
failed to install.
attoparsec-0.13.2.2-5fvnJr9WRPCJj7fMCLKoI7 depends on attoparsec- 
0.13.2.2
which failed to install.
cassava-0.5.1.0-CNxiRQP2h44BSkY7PLw3nv depends on cassava-0.5.1.0 which 
failed
to install.
criterion-1.4.1.0-1CDqJgx5SYk1Xphp8S6hvK depends on criterion-1.4.1.0 
which failed to install.
microstache-1.0.1.1-DUzquwnO02sC17piNr03EI depends on microstache- 
1.0.1.1 which failed to install.
monad-par-0.3.4.8-5Qx7yEAZEkjJbqZykcUjIa depends on monad-par-0.3.4.8 
which failed to install.
monad-par-extras-0.3.3-755mClpwIBoBMORFcN7gCY failed during the 
building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
scientific-0.3.6.2-65wDZeAE9ZIBkaesoEq4I0 failed during the building 
phase.
The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
statistics-0.14.0.2-GHJ1OiovyXP1FEjV1emzr8 depends on statistics- 
0.14.0.2 which failed to install.
text-short-0.1.2-JRY9FeZhxkoAZrj3rm5IJZ failed during the building 
phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
uuid-types-1.0.3-tE9Bfk2PgXDUPgbtamBdI failed during the building 
phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: Could you please provide command how you build your file? Basically, you need to specify `criterion` package as a dependency for your `Main.hs` file. And I'm not sure that `cabal install` is the right way. It's much easier to accomplish with `cabal` if you create package instead of single module file.

Comment: The actual error is in your `. . .`, so you will need to not snip that out. (The UI that cabal exposes for reporting errors is not super great in this particular way.)

Comment: I am using cabal. so, to build the package, the command I use is "cabal build" and "cabal test".

Answer (score -1):

One approach would be to use the Stack script interpreter to run this. In order to do so, you would first [install Stack](https://haskell-lang.org/get-started), then add the [script interpreter bits](https://haskell-lang.org/tutorial/stack-script) to the top of your file, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-11.10 script --optimize
import Criterion.Main

-- The function we're benchmarking.
fib m | m < 0     = error "negative!"
    | otherwise = go m
where
    go 0 = 0
    go 1 = 1
    go n = go (n-1) + go (n-2)

-- Our benchmark harness.
main = defaultMain [
bgroup "fib" [ bench "1"  $ whnf fib 1
            , bench "5"  $ whnf fib 5
            , bench "9"  $ whnf fib 9
            , bench "11" $ whnf fib 11
                ]
    ]
```

Note that I added the `--optimize` option on the second line to ensure that Stack would compile your code with optimizations on, instead of the default of using `runghc`.

And finally run the file with `stack fiber.hs` (or whatever you called the file).