# Could not find module ‘Criterion.Main’ when trying to benchmark haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, haskell-criterion

I cannot get Criterion to work. I followed the tutorial [here](http://www.serpentine.com/criterion/tutorial.html), installing Criterion by doing the following.

```
cabal update
cabal install -j --disable-tests criterion
```

when I try `ghc -O Fibber.hs` or `ghc -O --make Fibber` I receive the error

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Fibber.hs, Fibber.o )

Fibber.hs:1:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Criterion.Main’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
1 | import Criterion.Main
  |
```

I expect tests and diagnostics to be run and outputted to the console and an HTML file.
trying with stack results in the same error. I have solved this problem before with my own modules by including them in my `.cabal` file like so

```
library
  Exposed-Modules:
    Geometry.Sphere
    Geometry.Cuboid
    Geometry.Cube
```

But doing this same in this case does not resolve the issue. I have also tried [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50637221/could-not-find-module-criterion-main), but to no avail. I receive basically the same error:

```
/Users/me/Documents/projects/haskell/performance/criterion-1.5.13.0/Criterion/Fibber.hs:3:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘CriterionMain’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
3 | import CriterionMain
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Received ExitFailure 1 when running
Raw command: /Users/me/.stack/programs/aarch64-osx/ghc-9.2.2/bin/ghc-9.2.2 -i -i/Users/me/Documents/projects/haskell/performance/criterion-1.5.13.0/Criterion/ -hide-all-packages -fdiagnostics-color=always -packagebase -O2 /Users/me/Documents/projects/haskell/performance/criterion-1.5.13.0/Criterion/Fibber.hs
Run from: /Users/me/Documents/projects/haskell/performance/criterion-1.5.13.0/Criterion/
Standard output:

[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /Users/me/Documents/projects/haskell/performance/criterion-1.5.13.0/Criterion/Fibber.hs, /Users/me/Documents/projects/haskell/performance/criterion-1.5.13.0/Criterion/Fibber.o )
```

this is my `.cabal` file.

```
name:           criterion
version:        1.5.13.0
synopsis:       Robust, reliable performance measurement and analysis
license:        BSD3
license-file:   LICENSE
author:         Bryan O'Sullivan <bos@serpentine.com>
maintainer:     Ryan Scott <ryan.gl.scott@gmail.com>
copyright:      2009-2016 Bryan O'Sullivan and others
category:       Development, Performance, Testing, Benchmarking
homepage:       http://www.serpentine.com/criterion
bug-reports:    https://github.com/haskell/criterion/issues
build-type:     Simple
cabal-version:  >= 1.10
extra-source-files:
  README.markdown
  changelog.md
  examples/LICENSE
  examples/*.cabal
  examples/*.hs
tested-with:
  GHC==7.4.2,
  GHC==7.6.3,
  GHC==7.8.4,
  GHC==7.10.3,
  GHC==8.0.2,
  GHC==8.2.2,
  GHC==8.4.4,
  GHC==8.6.5,
  GHC==8.8.4,
  GHC==8.10.7,
  GHC==9.0.2,
  GHC==9.2.1

data-files:
  templates/*.css
  templates/*.tpl
  templates/*.js

description:
  This library provides a powerful but simple way to measure software
  performance.  It provides both a framework for executing and
  analysing benchmarks and a set of driver functions that makes it
  easy to build and run benchmarks, and to analyse their results.
  .
  The fastest way to get started is to read the
  <http://www.serpentine.com/criterion/tutorial.html online tutorial>,
  followed by the documentation and examples in the "Criterion.Main"
  module.
  .
  For examples of the kinds of reports that criterion generates, see
  <http://www.serpentine.com/criterion the home page>.

flag fast
  description: compile without optimizations
  default: False
  manual: True

flag embed-data-files
  description: Embed the data files in the binary for a relocatable executable.
               (Warning: This will increase the executable size significantly.)
  default: False
  manual: True

library
  exposed-modules:
    Criterion
    Criterion.Analysis
    Criterion.IO
    Criterion.IO.Printf
    Criterion.Internal
    Criterion.Main
    Criterion.Main.Options
    Criterion.Monad
    Criterion.Report
    Criterion.Types

  other-modules:
    Criterion.Main.Options.Internal
    Criterion.Monad.Internal

  other-modules:
    Paths_criterion

  build-depends:
    -- TODO: Eventually, we should bump the lower version bounds to >=2 so that
    -- we can remove some CPP in Criterion.Report. See #247.
    aeson >= 1 && < 2.1,
    ansi-wl-pprint >= 0.6.7.2,
    base >= 4.5 && < 5,
    base-compat-batteries >= 0.10 && < 0.13,
    binary >= 0.5.1.0,
    binary-orphans >= 1.0.1 && < 1.1,
    bytestring >= 0.9 && < 1.0,
    cassava >= 0.3.0.0,
    code-page,
    containers,
    criterion-measurement >= 0.1.1.0 && < 0.2,
    deepseq >= 1.1.0.0,
    directory,
    exceptions >= 0.8.2 && < 0.11,
    filepath,
    Glob >= 0.7.2,
    microstache >= 1.0.1 && < 1.1,
    js-chart >= 2.9.4 && < 3,
    mtl >= 2,
    mwc-random >= 0.8.0.3,
    -- TODO: Depend on optparse-applicative-0.17 as the minimum (see #258)
    optparse-applicative >= 0.13 && < 0.18,
    parsec >= 3.1.0,
    statistics >= 0.14 && < 0.16,
    text >= 0.11,
    time,
    transformers,
    transformers-compat >= 0.6.4,
    vector >= 0.7.1,
    vector-algorithms >= 0.4
  if impl(ghc < 7.6)
    build-depends:
      ghc-prim
  if !impl(ghc >= 8.0)
    build-depends:
      fail == 4.9.*,
      semigroups

  default-language: Haskell2010
  ghc-options: -Wall -funbox-strict-fields
  if impl(ghc >= 6.8)
    ghc-options: -fwarn-tabs
  if flag(fast)
    ghc-options: -O0
  else
    ghc-options: -O2

  if flag(embed-data-files)
    other-modules: Criterion.EmbeddedData
    build-depends: file-embed < 0.1,
                   template-haskell
    cpp-options: "-DEMBED"

Executable criterion-report
  Default-Language:     Haskell2010
  GHC-Options:          -Wall -rtsopts
  Main-Is:              Report.hs
  Other-Modules:        Options
                        Paths_criterion
  Hs-Source-Dirs:       app

  Build-Depends:
    base,
    base-compat-batteries,
    criterion,
    optparse-applicative >= 0.13

  if impl(ghc < 7.6)
    build-depends:
      ghc-prim

  if !impl(ghc >= 8.0)
    build-depends:
      semigroups

test-suite sanity
  type:                 exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs:       tests
  main-is:              Sanity.hs
  default-language:     Haskell2010
  ghc-options:          -Wall -rtsopts
  if flag(fast)
    ghc-options:        -O0
  else
    ghc-options:        -O2

  build-depends:
    HUnit,
    base,
    bytestring,
    criterion,
    deepseq,
    tasty,
    tasty-hunit

test-suite tests
  type:                 exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs:       tests
  main-is:              Tests.hs
  default-language:     Haskell2010
  other-modules:        Properties

  ghc-options:
    -Wall -threaded     -O0 -rtsopts

  build-depends:
    QuickCheck >= 2.4,
    base,
    base-compat-batteries,
    criterion,
    statistics,
    HUnit,
    tasty,
    tasty-hunit,
    tasty-quickcheck,
    vector,
    aeson

test-suite cleanup
  type:                 exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs:       tests
  default-language:     Haskell2010
  main-is:              Cleanup.hs

  ghc-options:
    -Wall -threaded     -O0 -rtsopts

  build-depends:
    HUnit,
    base,
    base-compat,
    bytestring,
    criterion,
    deepseq,
    directory,
    tasty,
    tasty-hunit

source-repository head
  type:     git
  location: https://github.com/haskell/criterion.git
```

Comment: "your" cabal file is criterion's cabal file. To enable criterion create a project and add criterion as a dependency for `Main.hs`

Comment: @Ismor I did not mean to be disingenuous, I more meant that this is the cabal file I am working with. My question is this: the file Fibber.hs is located in this criterion project, which seems to include criterion under `build-depends:` in multiple places. Could you be more precise? I am new to cabal and Haskell in general. Also, should the file be names `Main.hs` as opposed to `Fibber.hs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a dependency-solved REPL.

```
% cabal repl --build-depends criterion
> :l Fibber.hs
```

Another is to create a cabal package.

```
% mkdir Fibber
% mv Fibber.hs Fibber
% cd Fibber
% cabal init
<follow prompts, and say you're building an executable with filename Fibber.hs>
% vi Fibber.cabal
<add criterion to the build-depends: stanza>
% cabal run Fibber # or whatever executable name you gave it in the cabal init step
```

One advantage of the latter is that as you discover additional dependencies, you can make a record of all of them in a file, instead of having to remember to pass all of them every time when you start `cabal repl`. Another is that your code will be compiled, rather than interpreted; rather important for performance testing, which is presumably what you're doing if you need criterion!

Comment: Tysm! It's working now. My follow-up is this: how do I make sure cabal is compiling with optimizations?

Comment: it seems that `ghc-options: -O2` in the cabal file does the trick. Is that correct?

Comment: @LiamWhite Looks right to me!

Answer (score 0):

### 5 minutes Cabal explanation

Just a brief and not complete explanation about how `cabal` works so you can understand the error.

A project is made up of components: libraries and "runnables" (made up name for the sake of explanation). Each component has *its own* set of dependencies under `build-depends` tag.

Libraries do not have an entry point, so they don't need a `main` function and do not need to specify `main-is`. A cabal file has only [one public library](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/cabal-package.html?highlight=multiple%20libraries#library) which is the name of the package, at the top of the file tagged as `name`. You can have internal libraries, but thats another topic. In the `criterion`'s cabal file you see:

- The `name` is `criterion` (first line)
- The library build configuration under `library` tag. (dependencies, exposed modules, etc...)

Runnables do need a `main` function and a module marked as the `main-is`. Runnables  can be a executables, test suites or benchmarks. AFAIK, labeling a runnable as one of them, only affects the way `cabal` [compiles/install](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/cabal-commands.html?20install#cabal-v2-build) them via commands: `cabal build`, `cabal run`, `cabal test`, `cabal bench`, etc... For example `cabal build` will compile (by default) the library component and the executable components generating binary files one per executable, but `cabal test` will compile the library component and the test components, and then run the tests. In theory you can use `Criterion.Main.defaultMain` as the main function for a normal executable (define as en executable component in cabal file), in this case, cabal will generate an standalone exe which will run the benchmark on execution.

In the `criterion`'s cabal file you see on exectuable and three test suites:

- Executable named `criterion-report` under `app` folder
- Test suites `sanity`, `test` and `cleanup` under `test` folder with different main files each

Each of this components has different dependencies sets, and in particular, all of them depend on the `criterion` *library* which is the component defined in the same cabal file under section `library`, as explained above.

### So what's goint on with my error?

So essentialy, you want the `Fibber.hs` file to be a "runnable" file, either as a standalone binary or as a benchmark suite in a project. Therefore, you need to add it to a cabal file as you prefer. As a suggestion, avoid adding it to criterion's cabal file otherwise you'll be compiling criterion from source. Follow @DanielWagner answer and create a new project in which `Fibber.hs` is a main file and add `criterion` to its dependencies, or use the dependency-repl alternative.

Comment: @Ismor, thank you this is very helpful